# Access SATA drive via AHCI directly in efi shell?

Tags: driver, sata, uefi, efi

If we want to access(read/write) SATA drive via AHCI in EFI shell, is there any read/write interface used for this purpose ?

That is, does EFI shell application need to implement the AHCI spec to access drive ? (build command, issue command and process the command completion...)

Or application just calls specific "read/write" interfaces(like SCSI_PATH_THROUGH in Windows) and the ***"EFI ahci driver"*** converts these to low-level access routines ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Can you try to describe what you are actually trying to do, as opposed to the distilled abstract of it?

Comment: First I want to write the EFI shell application to access SATA drive via AHCI(I followed the ahci spec to completed this in DOS mode. To achieve this my application has to build command header, command table and corresponding PRD entries, then submit it !) Second, as I knew(?) there are efi drivers in efi shell. Thus if i want to develop the same application in efi shell, do I have to use the same way or there is high-level read/write interface(provided in efi drivers) to invoke ?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a driver available for the SATA drive in your UEFI, and the filesystem you wish to access is supported, then the act of reading/writing files is done by simple(ish) protocol calls.

The best example of this I can think of is the Linux kernel stub loader (which turns the Linux kernel into an EFI apllication able to load itself). Make sure to use a current 3.15 rc or later though, since there was a bug in earlier code.
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/firmware/efi/efi-stub-helper.c?id=refs/tags/v3.15-rc5 uses functions defined in https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/boot/compressed/eboot.c?id=refs/tags/v3.15-rc5 to do its file system accesses.

Alternatively, an application could do like GRUB and use methods for raw block device accesses - enabling the application to access filesystems not supported by UEFI itself.

And also, some applications (like rEFInd) enable additional filesystem support in UEFI by loading protocols (provided with the installation of rEFInd) at runtime.